# LINQ-to-SQL class doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanging & INotifyPropertyChanged if pulling from local database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, interface

I modified my data source in my LINQ-to-SQL class (by the old delete and drag back in method), and was surprised to see the INotifyPropertyChanging & INotifyPropertyChanged interfaces no longer implemented in the generated classes (MyDb.designer.cs).

The methods for the individual fields went from looking like this...

```
[Column(Storage="_Size", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
public string Size
{
    get
    {
        return this._Size;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Size != value))
        {
            this.OnSizeChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._Size = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Size");
            this.OnSizeChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

To looking like this...

```
[Column(Storage="_Size", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
public string Size
{
    get
    {
        return this._Size;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Size != value))
        {
            this._Size = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this happens and how it will affect my application?

Comment: That's strange. I don't know why it would happen. I do know, though, that without the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, your DataContext won't be able to track any changes made to those entities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your table has a primary key.

Comment: For future reference, this is the answer.

Comment: For bonus points do you know why it needs to have a primary key?

Comment: I reach here by searching around. and the exact problem is why a primary key is necessary?

Answer (score 5):

Check to make sure you did not set `ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;` or that you did not turn it off on the designer surface.

Answer (score 1):

Adding primary key will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change something in the designer after drag and drop? IIRC, there is a tracked property or some such.